# Receiving `KeyError: u'no item named XYZ'` error

Tags: python, csv, pandas

Here's the error I receive 
after running it I have this problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t1.py", line 255, in <module>
    pivot_rating = ratings.pivot(index='User-ID', columns='ISBN', values='Book-Rating')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4182, in pivot
    return pivot(self, index=index, columns=columns, values=values)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape.py", line 343, in pivot
    indexed = Series(self[values].values,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2003, in __getitem__
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 667, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 1655, in get
    _, block = self._find_block(item)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 1935, in _find_block
    self._check_have(item)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 1942, in _check_have
    raise KeyError('no item named %s' % com.pprint_thing(item))
KeyError: u'no item named Book-Rating'
Line 255 is pivot_rating = ratings.pivot(index='User-ID', columns='ISBN', values='Book-Rating')
```

After running the following code:

```
ratings = pd.read_csv('/Users/mona/Downloads/BX-Dump/BX-Book-Ratings.csv', sep=";", quotechar="\"", escapechar="\\")

print ratings
# <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> 
# Int64Index: 1149779 entries, 0 to 1149778 
# Data columns (total 3 columns): 
# 276725 1149779 non-null values 
# 034545104X 1149779 non-null values 
# 0 1149779 non-null values

pivot_rating = ratings.pivot(index='User-ID', columns='ISBN', values='Book-Rating')
```

However the file `BX-Book-Ratings.csv` has three columns and the third column is rating and each row is like this `"276725";"034545104X";"0"` . Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 1149779 entries, 0 to 1149778
Data columns (total 3 columns):
276725        1149779  non-null values
034545104X    1149779  non-null values
0             1149779  non-null values

Comment: and `ratings.columns`?

Comment: dtypes: int64(2), object(1)
Index([u'276725', u'034545104X', u'0'], dtype=object)

Comment: Your csv hasn't column names which you later use for pivot, spcify them expicetly. See example in update to my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `ratings` DataFrame has no column named `'Book-Rating'`:

```
>>> ratings = pd.DataFrame([[276725,"034545104X",0]], 
...                columns=['User-ID', 'ISBN', 'Book-Rating'])
>>> ratings.pivot(index='User-ID', columns='ISBN', values='Book-Rating')
ISBN     034545104X
User-ID
276725            0
```

Compare with:

```
>>> ratings.columns = ['User-ID', 'ISBN', 'BookRating']
>>> ratings.pivot(index='User-ID', columns='ISBN', values='Book-Rating')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
KeyError: u'no item named Book-Rating'
```

**Update**:

Solution in your case is to specify columns in code that loads data using `names` paramether. Try replace

```
pd.read_csv('/Users/mona/Downloads/BX-Dump/BX-Book-Ratings.csv', 
     sep=";", quotechar="\"", escapechar="\\")
```

with

```
pd.read_csv('/Users/mona/Downloads/BX-Dump/BX-Book-Ratings.csv', 
     header=None, names=['User-ID', 'ISBN', 'Book-Rating'],
     sep=";", quotechar="\"", escapechar="\\")
```